# Python Inherited Singleton Skeleton issues

Tags: python, python-3.x, singleton

As it stands i'm not sure if what i'm trying to do is even possible. My end goal was a Singleton skeleton, or parent class that could be reused between different (unique) instances. I understand that by definition a Singleton shouldn't be reusable and in the event that I need several of them, then I should probably rethink the structure. That being said, I wondered if it was possible and set out to try! Below is my latest attempt. The code is documented to the best of my ability (okayish) and should answer any additional questions.

My attempt was to use a single Singleton manager that would hold references to each unique singleton. And when creating a new instance of Singleton, it would check it's internal `dict[cls_name: cls_instance]` and if one already exists, it would instead return the already created instance. The issues, is that the manager correctly identifies that one exists, but rather than returning the existing instance. It strangely overwrites the original, and all variable references.. I'm not sure why it's doing this if i'm completely honest. Help!

```
class SingletonManager:
    """
        Managers unique singleton setup (hopefully!)
        Hoping to avoid doing this for every singleton, hence
        why i'm playing with an inherited singleton
    """

    __instance: 'SingletonManager._Inner' = None
    __active_instances: dict[str, object] = {}

    class _Inner:
        """
            Generic singleton inner
        """

        def register(self, instance: object):
            """
                Add an instance to Singleton.__active_instances dict
                with class_name and instance as the k,v pair if an entry
                doesn't already exist
            """

            instance_name = instance.__class__.__name__
            if not self.has_instance(instance_name):
                SingletonManager.instances()[instance_name] = instance
            else:
                raise Exception("How are we here?")

        def get_instance(self, instance_name: str) -> object:
            """
                Return an instance from the __active_instance dict
                with matching instance_name as key
            """

            return self.instances[instance_name]

        def has_instance(self, instance_name: str) -> bool:
            """
                Does __active_instances dict already contain key
                instance name?
            """

            return instance_name in self.instances

        @property
        def instances(self) -> dict:
            """
            Wrapper to grab managers __instance
            """
            return SingletonManager.instances()

    def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        """
        Generic singleton skeleton
        """

        if not cls.__instance:
            cls.__instance = cls._Inner()
        return cls.__instance

    @staticmethod
    def instances() -> dict:
        """
        Get reference to SingletonManager.__active_instances dict

        """

        return SingletonManager.__active_instances


class Singleton:
    """
    Base class for all singleton objects (hopefully)
    The hope is to inherit from and use this object
    rather than doing the traditional singleton setup

    Traditional setup:
        class obj:
            _instance = None

            class Singleton:
                def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
                    # do stuff

            def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
                if not obj._instance:
                    cls._instance = obj.Singleton(*args, **kwargs)
                return cls._instance

            def __getattr__(self, item):
                return getattr(obj._instance, item)

    As you can see it's alot of setup for each object that i'm hoping to avoid..
    """

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        pass

    def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        if not SingletonManager().has_instance(cls.__name__):
            instance = super(Singleton, cls).__new__(cls)
            SingletonManager().register(instance)
        else:
            instance = SingletonManager().get_instance(cls.__name__)
        return instance


class TestSingletonObj(Singleton):
    def __init__(self, name: str = None):
        super(TestSingletonObj, self).__init__(name)
        self.name = name
```

While testing..

```m
print(m.name)  # Steve
m2 = TestSingletonObj("John")
print(m2.name)  # John
print(m.name, m2.name, m is m2)  # John John True
```

If anyone can point out why the original instance is being overwritten rather than being returned. My only thought is it's a bug i've written, a bug in python, or it's an expected behavior with python's `MRO` that i'm unfamiliar with. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Why do you need a Singleton? Python isn't the best language to be enforcing this kind of thing.

Comment: Your pattern is more like Factory Method/Abstract Factory, or even Flyweight.

Comment: @PeterWood I don't specifically need anything. It's more of a hobby project that led into a "Can it be done" kinda thing! I'm unfamiliar with both of those concepts but i'll look into them, thank you